# User not receiving email to confirm email address in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, invalid-characters, email-confirmation

I'm setting up a MediaWiki page. I go to Preferences after I have logged in with my admin account. I try to send a confirmation email at my email address. I don't receive anything.

I'm the owner of all files and I have rwx rights. LocalSettings.php: $wgEmailAuthentication = true; . But $wgEmergencyContact and $wgPasswordSender have something like "apache@Œinvalid (it contains some invalid characters and literally the word invalid). I have changed them to myusername@domain and it still doesn't send a confirmation email. Maybe I'm putting the domain in wrong format? Does the problem have to do with LocalSettings or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this setting: [Manual:$wgSMTP](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSMTP)

Is it setup?

Comment: thank you very much, after I set up $wgSMTP in my LocalSettings it works!